# Hotlinking - htacces redirige a una página si cumple una condición

Tags: php, .htaccess

llevo mucho buscando la solución a este problema. Les explico.

Tengo una páginas con descarga de archivos zip, rar, pdf, doc, docx, xls, xlsx.

Las páginas y los archivos tienen esta estructura:

www.dominio.com/fotos/11/05/17/un-ave-de-color-negro-**x4S12qlJ.html** *(página)*
www.dominio.com/fotos/11/05/17/**x4S12qlJ**.zip *(archivo .zip)*

www.dominio.com/fotos/11/05/17/mamifero-de-clima-frio-**uWe36Sqt.html** *(página)*
www.dominio.com/fotos/11/05/17/**uWe36Sqt**.zip *(archivo .zip)* ... etc

No tengo problema que se lleven el ancho de banda con las fotos, el problema son con los archivos .zip, rar, etc.. que son enlazados. Lo que quiero es si desde otros dominios enlazan a www.dominio.com/fotos/11/05/17/**uWe36Sqt.zip** sea redireccionado a www.dominio.com/fotos/11/05/17/mamifero-de-clima-frio-**uWe36Sqt.html**

*Tengo que precisar que la página es con php y mysql*

¿Es posible hacer esto?
Gracias

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que quieres hacer, el resultado que quieres obtener. Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/101202/edit) para explicarte mejor y si has escrito algo de código al respecto compártelo también.

Comment: Sí, tal vez no precisé bien. La idea es que cualquier dominio que enlace a un archivo (por ejemplo uWe36Sqt.zip), redirija a la pagina que contiene los detalles del archivo y se descargue desde ahí.